# BB 10 cascades signals when user closing the App

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Is there any signal that fires , while the user terminating the app. I need to clear the data from database On terminating the App.

I hope that get a proper solution here,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

void QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit () is the signal you are looking for.
Please see
https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit

Comment: can i use  bool boo= QObject::connect(app, SIGNAL( manualExit() ), this, SLOT( onManualExit() )); but app is running in background after closing it..